# How to find paragraphs contain no embolden character?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, libreoffice-writer, typography

In Word or Libre Writer, is there a way to find any paragraph that contains no embolden character? I would like to delete them. I can go to the Advanced Find and choose `Wildcard` as well as `Not bold`, but I don't know how to tell it only select paragraphs.

[image]

Comment: a quick hack is to use `* * *`

Answer (score 1):

I do not use LibreWriter. In Word, I would use a macro along the following lines.

```
Sub BoldRequired()
    '   Charles Kenyon 20 September 2020
    '   remove all paragraphs that have no bold characters
    Dim oParagraph As Paragraph
    Dim oDocument As Document
    Dim rngParagraph As Range
    Dim iCount As Double
    Set oDocument = ActiveDocument
    For Each oParagraph In oDocument.Paragraphs
        Set rngParagraph = oParagraph.Range
        With rngParagraph.Find
            .Text = ""
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Execute
            If .Found = False Then Let rngParagraph.Text = ""
            .ClearFormatting
        End With
    Next oParagraph
    Set oDocument = Nothing
    Set oParagraph = Nothing
    set rngParagraph = Nothing
End Sub
```